# Multiple Delete using JQuery Ajax and Code Igniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am currently working on a program that uses php jquery and bootstrap, I want to delete multiple data using checkbox. I search and found out that it must use AJAX to passing the paramater from view to controller. The Jquery work find and can get the value from checkbox. But when I use Ajax, the button not working. Nothing change. Please help me to find the problem on my code. Thank you

My Controller

```
public function hapusbeberapa()
    {
        $this->model_security->getsecurity();
        $this->load->model('model_barang');
        $arr = $this->input->post('data');

        //$arrcode= json_encode($arr);
        foreach($arr as $id)
            {
                $query = $this->model_barang->getID($id);
                if($query->num_rows()>0)
                {
            $this->model_barang->getdelete($id);
            //$this->session->set_flashdata('info',"Data Berhasil Dihapus");
                } 
            }
    }
```

My Model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_barang extends CI_model {

    public function getdelete($key)
    {
        $this->db->where('IDBarang',$key);
        $this->db->delete('tBarang');

    }

    public function getID($key)
    {
        $this->db->where('IDBarang',$key);
        $query = $this->db->get('tbarang'); 
        return $query;
    }
}
```

My View

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#btnhapus").click(function(){

            var favorite = [];

            $.each($("input[name='checkboxlist']:checked"), function(){            

                favorite.push($(this).val());

            });

                $.post("<?php echo site_url(barang/hapusbeberapa) ?>"+actMult, {data:favorite}););

        });

    });

</script>

</script>
```

Comment: what is `actMult` in the url you're passing in `$.post();`

Comment: I just following a tutorial from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458405/trying-to-submit-multiple-checkbox-values-via-ajax-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use your script as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btnhapus").click(function(){

        var favorite = [];

        $.each($("input[name=checkboxlist]:checked"), function(){            

            favorite.push($(this).val());

        });

            $.post("<?php echo site_url(/barang/hapusbeberapa) ?>", {data:favorite}, function(returnData){
            console.log(returnData);
      });

    });

});

</script>
```

it will work for sure,
the result will be same as you `echo` in controller's function, and check `console log` for check result, you can also check it by using `alert(returnData)` instead of `console.log(returnData)`.

hope it helps

Comment: I change the code as you told me, but nothing happend. The web only show the confirmation dialog and then the data is still there.
This also happend when I use AJAX or jquery to update the data

Comment: its could be because you didn't echo any message in controller

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
var favorite = [];
$.each($("input[name='checkboxlist']:checked"), function(){            
   favorite.push($(this).val());
});
favorite = favorite.join(); 
$.post
...
```

In Controller

```
$arr = $this->input->post('data');
$arr = explode(',', $arr);
```

Comment: why `explode`, `data` is already an `array`, so we don't need